# How to configure Spring Boot Tomcat Basic Auth together with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm currently trying to make a Spring Boot app. I've managed to create successfully user authentication using LDAP and custom logic.

However, I'm trying to add another layer of security on top of that, something like "htaccess" to prevent unauthorized users from even seeing the web page (client requirement), as well as stop Google from indexing the page. This can be a single predefined user (doesn't need to be connected to ldap auth).

I've read about configuring the tomcat realm, tomcat-users etc. but since it's Spring Boot app with embedded tomcat, I can't find a place to successfully configure it.

Does anyone have any idea how to create such setup?

Comment: Just configure basic-auth with Spring Security. Why does it have to be more complex. You are running everything through spring boot and thus spring security just put the configuration in there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, I need to add second authentication provider? How will it determine whether i want to login to a system (LDAP) or just access the page (Basic)?